# What is the use of variadic constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, variadic-functions, variadic

Consider following program:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Test
{
    Test(...)
    {
        std::cout<<"Variadic constructor\n";
    }
};
int main()
{
    Test t;
    t={3,4,5};
}
```

I think it is variadic constructor. Does the C++ standard says that constructor can be variadic? What is the use of such constructor? What is the rationale for allowing variadic constructor?

Comment: So you don't have to write multiple constructors. This one isn't very useful, by the way, it doesn't provide any info as to what the parameters actually are.

Comment: For the first question: functions can be variadic, constructor is a function. Why can't it be variadic?

Comment: @MrLister: It would be better if you write an answer that explains its usefulness using an example.

Comment: Now that we have variadic templates, the varargs method is pretty much useless.  Lack of type safety and all.

Comment: Pravasi Meet, but as @lisyarus says, a variadic constructor is exactly as useful as any other variadic function. Are you really inquiring about what variadic functions are for at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's try to answer your questions one by one:

> I think it is variadic constructor.

You are correct.

> Does the C++ standard says that constructor can be variadic?

IANALL, but, I think so. Why not? Constructor is just a (member) function.

> What is the use of such constructor?

Like any other variadic function - to pass a variable number of arguments. It also has the same problems, mostly *no* *type* *safety* as any other variadic function. For example, let's say you need a list of (C) strings, you could do something like See live demo [here](http://ideone.com/nS2Kuw).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>
struct Test
{
    Test(int n,...)
    {
        va_list va;
        va_start(va, n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
             char const *s = va_arg(va, char*);
             std::cout<<"s=" << s << std::endl;
        }
        va_end(va);
    }
};
int main()
{
     Test t{3, "3","4","5"};
}
```

Keep in mind that for this to work, you need at least one "non-variadic" parameter. So a "pure variadic" constructor, like the one you show, doesn't make much sense in portable C++ code. For any particular platform, you may know how to access the parameters even without the non-variadic parameter, so, this might work:

```
     Test t={"3","4","5", NULL};
```

> What is the rationale for allowing variadic constructor?

"It's C compatible and someone might have a use of it", I guess. If you know your way around `<cstdarg>`, it can be an effective tool. Of course, with C++11, you should most probably use variadic templates / perfect forwarding and initialization lists instead. But, with C++98 you didn't have these tools.

Comment: Wonderful answer & nice explanation.

Comment: Your code contains compilation errors. (See live demo http://ideone.com/VkQmwx ) variable va should be of va_list not va_arg. (See working code here: http://ideone.com/nS2Kuw )

Comment: @PravasiMeet thanks, I should have checked it, of course, but it was more of an illustration than a demo, that's why it slipped...